# PHP while loop, display in pairs of two

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, while-loop

In Wordpress, I am creating a slider to slide through some content that the user specify. I am using ACF (advanced custom fields) if anyone is familiar with that, however what I am trying to accomplish is to show two content items at a time, while sliding through the jQuery slider.

Here is my loop:

```
<?php while(has_sub_field('popular_topic')): ?>
    <li>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('popular_topic_image'); ?>" alt="" />
            <div class="img-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="slider-content">
                <?php 

                $len = 60;
                $popularTopicTitle = get_sub_field('popular_topic_title');

                $newContent = substr($popularTopicTitle, 0, $len); 
                if(strlen($newContent) < strlen($popularTopicTitle)) {
                    $newContent = $newContent.'...';
                }
                echo '<p>'.$newContent.'</p>';

                ?>
                <a class="more-arrow" href="<?php the_sub_field('popular_topic_link'); ?>">Read More</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This is currently working, however it only shows one slide.  I want it to show two slides and a time. Is there something I can do with a counter?  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

my syntax might be a little off but maybe give this a shot?

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php while(has_sub_field('popular_topic')): ?>
    <?php
        $len = 60;
        $popularTopicTitle = get_sub_field('popular_topic_title');
        $newContent = substr($popularTopicTitle, 0, $len); 
        if(strlen($newContent) < strlen($popularTopicTitle)) {
            $newContent = $newContent.'...';
        }
        $contentVar[$i] = array (
            'img'   =>  the_sub_field('popular_topic_image'),
            'title' =>  $newContent,
            'link'  =>  the_sub_field('popular_topic_link')
        );
        $i++;
    ?>  
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php $j = 0; ?>
<?php while ($j < $i) : ?>
<li>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="<?php echo $contentVar[$j]['img']; ?>" alt="" />
        <div class="img-wrapper"></div>
        <div class="slider-content">
            <p><?php echo $contentVar[$j]['title']; ?></p>
            <a class="more-arrow" href="<?php echo $contentVar[$j]['link']; ?>">Read More</a>
        </div>
        <?php $j++; ?>
        <?php if ($j <= $i) : ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $contentVar[$j]['img']; ?>" alt="" />
            <div class="img-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="slider-content">
                <p><?php echo $contentVar[$j]['title']; ?></p>
                <a class="more-arrow" href="<?php echo $contentVar[$j]['link']; ?>">Read More</a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</li>
<?php $j++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```